# How do I 'merge' items within a flexbox, so they don't overflow?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make my personal website responsive. On the landing page (in desktop view) there are three links arranged in a flex box row. Each link itself is also a flexbox, with the items arranged in a column:

[image: Desktop view]

The CSS for this is as follows:

```
//Parent container:
.homemain-links {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

//Link:
.info-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding:10%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When the screen size shifts from desktop to mobile, I want the links to switch from a row to a column. However when this happens, the link contents spill out:

[image]

CSS:

```
@media (max-width:576px) {
    .homemain-links{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;  
    }
    .info-container {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    }
}
```

I've tried using `width:auto height:auto`  which worked, but the div container switched from a square to a rectangle, and I'm wanting to retain the square shape.

So is there a way to 'merge' a flexbox with the items within in, so that the items stay within it's boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, the reason they spill out of the div container is because you have set a fixed width/height. You can try to set it with a relative values that's equal in order to have it adapt to screen sizes as well as retain the square shape, i.e., `6.5rem` for both width/height or other similar relative values in CSS.